# Linked server between SQL SERVER and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2012, odbc, linked-server

I have a linked server to a PostgreSQL database from SQL server 2012 64bit using ODBC

I am able to see the databases on this server, and able run select query on some tables but accessing some table getting this error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PO_SERVER" returned message "ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xc2 0x81 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252";
Error while executing the query".
Msg 7306, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot open the table ""projop"."public"."parties"" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PO_SERVER".
```

Comment: The real error message is the `ERROR: character with byte sequence...` you conveniently truncated with your screen shot. Please don't post screen shots: [edit] the question and cut and paste the complete error message as formatted text.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe done posted the full error message

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL table contains the Unicode character `\u0081`, a non-printable control character that cannot be represented in the Windows-1252 encoding.

Either use a different encoding with SQL Server (if that is possible), or use a different character in the PostgreSQL database.